# Derivative of ax^b with respect to lnx

Tags: calculus

I need to take the derivative of a long function with respect, the function is already in logs.

Something like $\log(y)= 10+c \log(d) \log(x)+ax^b$

I am guessing the last part should be come $abx$. But I am using methods that I haven't used before.

$\frac{dax^b}{d [ \ln x] } = a \frac{x^b}{d [\ln x]} = \frac{ a(dx b x^{b-1})}{[ dx/x}$  simplifying to $abx$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand how your two lines of equations relate to each other.  For the first, do you want $\frac {d(\log y)}{dx}$ or $\frac {dy}{dx}?$  No, the last part doesn't become $abx$ and we don't guess.  For the second, you would use the chain rule, $\frac d{d(\ln x)}=\frac d{dx}\cdot \frac {dx}{d \ln x}$, but I am not convinced this is what you are looking for.

Comment: You can typeset your equations using LaTeX syntax (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/480/math-markup-diagrams-etc-pointers-please/483#483)

Answer (score 3):

Use the chain rule with y = log(x):

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial log(x))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{1}{x}$$

Hence, we conclude that:

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\cdot x$$

Comment: You can typeset your equations using LaTeX syntax (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/480/math-markup-diagrams-etc-pointers-please/483#483)

Comment: I'm new to Latek... you can probably tell, since I've just joined and have few reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider writing $ax^b = a e^{b \ln(x)}$, so the entire right side is in terms of $\ln(x)$.